# insert null after every 7th element in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to insert one null element after every 7 elements in the list:

I tried following but it doesn't insert '' at the end (after 7th element):

```
mapline = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']
i = 7
while i < len(mapline):
    mapline.insert(i, '')
    i += 8

>>> mapline
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n']

>>> len(mapline)
15
```

I had to append '' at the end:

```
>>> mapline.append('')
>>> mapline
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', '', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', '']
```

Is there any alternative to resolve this?

Comment: Why is `i += 8` if you want to do every `7`? Is it because the first insert grows the list? What if the list were longer? Or is this realistic data?

Comment: I would suggest against using this approach with `insert`, it will be inefficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An off-by-one error. Simply change the condition to `<=` if you want the last element to "count":

```
while i <= len(mapline):
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
mapline = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n']

newline = []

for i, line in enumerate(mapline):
    if (i + 1) % 7 == 0:
        newline.append('')
    newline.append(i)
```

Comment: you can just use `enumerate(seq, 1)` to start counting from `1`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: This approach scales much better than `insert`, although, it creates a new list. But I would go with something like this... +1

Answer (score 0):

the loop has to run one more time in order to add the null element

```
while i < len(mapline) + 1 :
```